# function static get from lambda is safe?

Tags: multithreading, lambda, static

```
A& instA1()
{
    static A a;
    a.init(); 
    return a;
}




A& instA2()
{
    static A a = [](){
        A a = new A();
        a.init(); 
        return a;
    }();
    return a;
}
```

about use

```
// thread1
A& a1 = instA1();
A& a2 = instA2();
// thread2
A& a1 = instA1();
A& a2 = instA2();
```

**A::init() is not a multithread safe fun. **

In C++11, about get a single A, the instA1 is multithread not safe  , and ** instA2 is multithread safe?**